# Images does not get displayed in ImageButton

Tags: android, image, bitmap, inputstream, outputstream

I am displaying images from the string path (which I retrieve from database) and I have no problem displaying one image. But when I have 4 images, only one image (the first image) gets displayed and the others are not displayed. My code is as followed:

```
 try{
    name.setText(nameString);
    school.setText(schoolString);
    psupervisor.setText(info.getPsupervisor());
    pdate.setText(info.getPdate());
    a.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(info.getPtick1()));
    b.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(info.getPtick2()));
    c.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(info.getPtick3()));
    pcomment1.setText(info.getPcomment1());
    psignature1.setImageBitmap(resizeSignatureBitmap(info.getPsignature1()));
    pcomment2.setText(info.getPcomment2());
    psignature2.setImageBitmap(resizeSignatureBitmap(info.getPsignature2()));
    pdate2.setText(info.getPdate2());
    d.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(info.getPtick4()));
    e.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(info.getPtick5()));
    f.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(info.getPtick6()));
    pcomment3.setText(info.getPcomment3());
    psignature3.setImageBitmap(resizeSignatureBitmap(info.getPsignature3()));
    pcomment4.setText(info.getPcomment4());
    psignature4.setImageBitmap(resizeSignatureBitmap(info.getPsignature4()));
    Log.d("PREPOST: ", log2);
    db.close();
 }
 catch(Exception ex){}

}

//method to resize the bitmap before displaying
 public Bitmap resizeSignatureBitmap(String imagePath){

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
            is = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
    try {
            is.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
            is = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // here w and h are the desired width and height
    options.inSampleSize = Math.max(options.outWidth/w, options.outHeight/h);
    // bitmap is the resized bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);

     return bitmap;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with what I'm doing? Please kindly point my mistake out as I can't find my mistake. No errors, nothing, just that it doesn't get displayed. By default, it only displays one image and it's always the first image (psignature1) and if I comment it out, then second image (psignature2) would get displayed but the rest would not be displayed.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: could you add the layout where psignature* is defined?

Comment: @blackbelt it's just a normal imagebutton, same for all four therefore I couldn't understand when only one of the image for the imagebutton can be displayed.

Comment: is it so hard to post a snippet of layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//method to resize the bitmap before displaying
public Bitmap resizeSignatureBitmap(String imagePath){

 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
InputStream is = null;
try {
        is = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // here w and h are the desired width and height
options.inSampleSize = Math.max(options.outWidth/w, options.outHeight/h);
// bitmap is the resized bitmap
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
is=null;
 return bitmap;
}
```

write your method like this..and you are done.

Comment: thanks for the help but that didn't help. It still remained the same, with the only the first image appearing.

Comment: its ok.glad to know it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your psignature1, psignature2, psignature3
is defined by the same id

Maybe your code is like this

```
psignature1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.psignature1);
psignature2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.psignature1);
psignature3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.psignature1);
```

Try changing each id

---

Here's my bitmap compressor for images in sd card,
just edit it

```
public Bitmap compressBitmapResource(String filePath, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {

     // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
     final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

     options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
     BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

     // Calculate inSampleSize
     options.inSampleSize = calculateBitmapSize(options, reqWidth,
     reqHeight);

     // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
     options.inPurgeable = true;
     options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
     return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

}

    public int calculateBitmapSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```